# Convert the child object pointer to the base class(from another namespace) pointer

Tags: c++

For my existing code which is working, it has statement like:

```
namespace aa{
    class a{} 
    class b: public a {....}

    class x
    {
       a* function(){ 
         b* object = new b(...);
         ....
         return b;
       }
    }
}
```

There is the implicit convertion from b* to a* during the "function" call. And it returns a*. It works.

Now I have move the class to another namespace like:

```
namepsace newaa{
  class a{}
}

namespace aa{
    class b: public newaa::a {....}

    class x
    {
       newaa::a* function(){ 
         b* object = new b(...);
         ....
         return b;
       }
    }
}
```

With above changes, I got the error: cannot covert 'aa::b*' to 'newaa:a*' in return, why?

And if I use dynamic_cast 
    return dynamic_cast(b)
It pass the compilation but I got some other errors in other files.

Comment: Post real code that we can compile ourselves please. There are so many small errors here that it's impossible to guess what your real code looks like.

Comment: also, "It pass the compilation but I got some errors" - _which are?_

Comment: "code which is working" followed by code that doesn't even compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your code working with these fixes; mainly: return `object` from `function()`, not the type `b`:

```
namespace newaa{
    class a{};
}
namespace aa{
    class b: public newaa::a {};
    class x
    {
        newaa::a* function(){ 
            b* object = new b();
                return object;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Given that the same error exists in OP's "working" code, clearly he did not show the code that causes the actual error.